# ROS Answers SE migration: gtest for ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a guide similar to [this one that I think it is for ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/gtest) that explain how to start writing and using gtest for ROS2 applications?

Also, does calling colcon test run the gtest tests?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351474/gtest-for-ros2/) by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2020-05-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-05-05**:
Simple answer: yes

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2020-05-05**:
can you point me where to find that guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I can't give you a guide  but I can give you examples

- https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/master/nav2_system_tests
- https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/master/nav2_recoveries/test
- https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/master/nav2_costmap_2d
- https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/tree/eloquent-devel/test

Really it mostly looks like gtest, just using ROS as if it were any other arbitrary library.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2